# metodo update (sqlite) não atualiza dados do banco

Tags: android, sqlite

tenho um listView que exibe os itens do banco com um botão atualizar, esse botão chama a tela com os valores setados nos editText, eu edito, clico em salvar, ele me retorna a mensagem de atualizado com sucesso, porem não atualiza os dados, eles continuam aparecendo iguais no listView.

método que recebe os valores e chama o metodo atualiza do banco:

```
public void atualizar(View view){
    Livro livro = new Livro();
    livro.setTitulo(edtTitulo.getText().toString());
    livro.setAutor(edtAutor.getText().toString());
    livro.setEditora(edtEditora.getText().toString());

    LivroCRUD livroCRUD = new LivroCRUD(this);
    try {
        livroCRUD.atualizar(livro);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Livro Atualizado com sucesso!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Não foi possivel atualizar.....!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

método que atualiza as informações no banco:

```
public void atualizar(Livro livro) throws Exception{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("titulo ", livro.getTitulo());
    values.put("autor ", livro.getAutor());
    values.put("editora ", livro.getEditora());

    db.update("livro ", values, "_id = ? ", new String[]{" "+livro.getId()});
}
```

método que preenche a lista:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LivroCRUD livroCRUD = new LivroCRUD(this);
    try {
        List<Livro> lista = livroCRUD.buscarTodos();

        ListView lvPrincipal = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvPrincial);
        lvPrincipal.setAdapter(new LivroAdapter(this, lista));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Não foi possivel carregar a lista.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

método de clique do botão atualizar no adapter, ele pega os valores e passa para a activity "AddUpdateActivity"

```
Button btnAtualizar = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnChamaAtualizar);
    btnAtualizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Livro livro = new Livro();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddUpdateActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("titulo", lista.get(auxPosition).getTitulo());
            intent.putExtra("autor", lista.get(auxPosition).getAutor());
            intent.putExtra("editora", lista.get(auxPosition).getEditora());
            intent.putExtra("_id", lista.get(auxPosition).getId());
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Porquê o espaço a seguir ao nome da tabela("livro ")? Porquê um espaço antes do Id(" "+livro.getId())?

Comment: Além que alterar os dados no BD pode não ser suficiente para que a *ListView* seja actualizada.

Comment: retirei os espaços, e realmente o listView não atualiza na hora, eu tenho que sair e voltar para a app, para ver os dados inseridos e removidos, mas alteração realmente não funciona, tem alguma outra forma de escrever os argumentos do método update?

Comment: Para lhe dar uma resposta poste o código onde está a preencher a listView pela primeira vez.

Comment: adicionei o oncreate da activity que sempre preeenche a lista com todos os dados do banco
e o metodo do botão atualizar que pega os valores e passa para a activity de adição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não está a actualizar os dados do banco porque os valores passados ao método `db.update()` estão mal: remova o espaço em `"livro "` e `" "+livro.getId()`:

```
db.update("livro", values, "_id = ? ", new String[]{""+livro.getId()});
```

Além disso, no método `atualizar(View view)`, tem que atribuir o Id ao *Livro* que quer actualizar, para que ele seja passado ao método `db.update()`:

```
public void atualizar(View view){
    Livro livro = new Livro();
    livro.setTitulo(edtTitulo.getText().toString());
    livro.setAutor(edtAutor.getText().toString());
    livro.setEditora(edtEditora.getText().toString());

    livro.setId = id;//O id deve ser recuperado do Extra passado à AddUpdateActivity

    LivroCRUD livroCRUD = new LivroCRUD(this);
    try {
        livroCRUD.atualizar(livro);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Livro Atualizado com sucesso!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Não foi possivel atualizar.....!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Alterar os dados no BD pode não ser suficiente para que a *ListView* seja actualizada, a não ser que esteja a utilizar o [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) em conjunto com um [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html).

Da forma como tem o código estruturado não é fácil colocar aqui uma solução pronta.

O que tem de fazer é informar o *LivroAdapter* das alterações para que ele actualize a *ListView*.

Há varias formas, uma possível é declarar um método no *LivroAdapter* que actualize a lista interna.

```
public void actualizaLista(List<Livro> lista){

    this.nomeDaSuaLista = lista; 
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Depois dos dados serem alterados no BD chame assim:

```
List<Livro> lista = livroCRUD.buscarTodos();
lvPrincipal.getAdapter().actualizaLista(lista);
```

Comment: eu já estava pesquisando uma forma de atualizar a lista apos um inserção ou alteração, obrigado pelas dicas
mas infelizmente mesmo retirando os espaços parece que o banco de dados ainda não atualiza pelo método update do meu código.

Comment: Veja a edição à resposta.

Comment: consegui finalmente fazer atualizar, obrigado pelas dicas @ramaral, o que fiz foi instanciar a minha classe livro fora de todos os metodos, não sei se global é o termo correto.
agora vou pesquisar sobre o listview atualizar no momento da alteração pelas dicas que você me deu, obrigado

Comment: estou tendo certa dificuldade com o `notifyDataSetChanged();`, eu criei o metodo `atualizalista` no `adapter`, porem a linha `lvPrincipal.getAdapter().actualizaLista(lista);` não funciona. Coloquei ela no `onResume` porque quando adiciono ou atualizo um dado, minha app volta para a activity que contem a lista.

Comment: Antes de chamar o método está a fazer `List<Livro> lista = livroCRUD.buscarTodos();`?

Comment: sim, o problema esta em que depois do `.getAdapter()` ele não detecta o meu metodo `atualizaLista(lista)` do `LivroAdapter`.

Comment: Sem conhecer este novo contexto é difícil dizer qualquer coisa. É melhor você fazer outra pergunta colocando a parte relevante do código.

Answer (score -2):

Quando você vai passar o parâmetro está informando um array, porém está usando " = ? ", remove esse "new String", ficando:

```
db.update("livro ", values, "_id = ? ", livro.getId());
```

Comment: Isso não vai compilar!

Comment: realmente o metodo update requer um whereArgs, sem o array não compila